# Unable to change Python path in CentOS

Tags: linux, python-2.7, shell, centos

I have Python installed in the server and its default path is:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7
```

But it somehow got changed and when I am running my programs this is what i am getting.

```
File "/home/satbeersl/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
```

It got changed to :"/home/satbeersl/miniconda2/lib/python2.7.
How can i change it back. I tried:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/python2.7
```

Its still not changing. New to linux, can't figure out what to do. None of my programs seem to be working suddenly. Help.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you are using virtual environments for Python on your system - they alter the real path to Python and pip to a project location.

Try `deactivate` command if you are using virtualenv to stop the virtual environment.

If you still haven't tried it in terminal ask `which python` and `which python3` to check the paths and compare them.

Hope this helps.

Comment: when i do which Python, it gives `/home/satbeersl/miniconda2/bin/python` but it should have been `/usr/lib/python2.7`. How do i change the path?

Comment: Can you give us the output of `echo $PATH`? Are you sure that the Python 2,7 files are exactly at `/usr/lib/python2.7`? Could you try calling Python2.7 with `/usr/bin/python2.7`?

Comment: echo $PATH gives: @Teddy Markov, `/home/satbeersl/miniconda2/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/home/satbeersl/.local/bin:/home/satbeersl/bin` And /usr/bin/python2.7 gives `Python 2.7.5 (default, Oct 11 2015, 17:47:16)
[GCC 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.` Have i screwed up something really bad?

Comment: I am just assuming that they are at `/usr/lib/python2.7`. Because the programs were working fine till yesterday. This new path only came up after I tried to install Pandas. So, I am guessing its the change of path. Please help. And when i do which python, it gives me `/home/satbeersl/miniconda2/bin/python` the new one again.

Comment: As far as I can see your $PATH is messed up. I think it is changing the paths as usually it should look like this: `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bi‌​n:`
Please try:
`export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bi‌​n:`

Comment: Does not work. `File "/home/satbeersl/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 437, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='survey.modul.ac.at', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /piwikAnalytics/?module=API&method=Live.getLastVisitsDetails&idSite=34&format=csv&token_auth=35a2c1b4707f45cebfbdaa7f6c3af267&period=day&date=2016-07-14&filter_limit=2000 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f3f13b21550>:...`

Comment: This way you will create a symlink to the real location:
`ln -nsf /home/satbeersl/miniconda2/bin/python /usr/lib/python2.7`

Comment: Same error..Tried everything. Is there a way to uninstall this new version of Python

Comment: Have you tried setting the path for python in the beginning of the files like this: `#!usr/bin/env python` and then run the script from the shell

Comment: Yup `#!usr/bin/env python
cd /home/satbeer/piwik/;
python piwik_crawler_for_raw_csv.py yesterday
` . No success.

Comment: I ran out of ideas, sorry :/ Think what might have caused the issue at first place and eventually revert actions.

Comment: Hmm. Even I ran out of ideas. Will keep trying